# Dynamically build Google form based on specific row in sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I'm trying to create a dynamic Google form template that repopulates the questions AND the answers each time it's opened, based on URL parameter that directs to a specific, CHANGING row in a Google sheet.

For instance, let's say this is my sheet:

```
+---+----A----+----B---+-------C------+---D---+
| 1 | Product | Size   | Max quantity | Gift? |
+---+---------+--------+--------------+-------+
| 2 | Shirt1  | M,S    | 5            | Yes   |
| 3 | Shirt2  | L,M,S  | 1            | No    |
+---+---------+--------+--------------+-------+
```

My wesite offers the user to order Shirt1 or Shirt2, and opens the same form, but populates it differently based on a URL parameter.

So for ?row=2 at the end of the URL, the form will offer sizes M & S, limit the quantity to anywhere between 1-5, and offer a checkbox for a gift wrap.

But for ?row=3, the form will offer sizes L, M & S, and not display the quantity and the gift wrap questions at all, as they're redundant.

How would you approach this? Is this possible at all?
I'm having a hard time passing the parameter, to start with.

(Pre-filled is not the answer here, as I want it to affect the questions, not just the answers. Also FormRanger won't do here, as the source for repopulating the form changes depending on the users' actions)